zsh,how to change the button for executing commands to the "enter" key?
Installed zsh, but the problem is that the commands in it are not executed through the key enter,but ctrl + j, how can you change to enter ?

What Ubuntu version are you using, and how exactly did you install zsh? The Enter key would normally emit Ctrl-M and that should also be bound to accept-line - what is the output of bindkey '^M'
